# Feedback/Patterns on creating a protocol adaptor

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rs, mule

I have a backend system that currently returns a domain object.  I want to build a REST & SOAP front end using mule.  To create responses that are REST or SOAP based, and ensure that the backend is protocol agnostic, I am thinking about creating two protocol adapters (REST and SOAP).  It is unclear to me if it is better to create a mule translator for the service, which understands the protocol and delegates to generate an appropriate response, or just create two class interfaces (using JAX-RS/JAX-WS annotations) to the service.

I'm not finding much literature, best practices, or design patterns on the subject.  Can someone point me to some useful material or provide their opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing transformers for message formatting would be a waste of time.

You should write service classes with JAX-RS/JAX-WS annotations, transports exist for both.

For a REST service you can use the Jersey transport:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/JERSEY/User's+Guide

For SOAP service you can use the CXF transport (also supports JAX-RS):
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/CXF/Building+a+web+service

Note: You don't need mule for this at all, both Jersey and CXF run in a servlet container like tomcat.